# PHP ssh2.sftp stopped working

Tags: php, ubuntu

Below is code that's been running for quite some time and this week it stopped working. I've narrowed it down to the line where it fails on the 'fopen' statement.  I get the proper echos if I comment the fopen line out.  At first I thought it was a rights problem on the remote server, but I had the same thing happen with a different server as well.

I am not really getting an error message.  I basically get a browser message that the page cannot load.

This is running on PHP 5.5.9 on an Ubuntu server.  We did receive updates to a number of php packages from ubuntu on 8/11.

Here is the code:

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('fe01.xyz.com', 22);
if (!$connection) die('Connection failed');
echo "connected<br>";
$u=ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
if (!$u) :
   echo "auth failed ";
   exit;
else:
  echo "auth success<br>";
endif;

$outdata=file_get_contents("files/ulti99.csv");
$resSFTP = ssh2_sftp($connection);  
if (!$resSFTP):
  echo "SFTP Connection Failed";
  exit;
else:
  echo "SFTP Connection Succuess<br>";
endif;  

$resFile = fopen("ssh2.sftp://{$resSFTP}/ulti99.csv", 'w');  // failing
echo "after open";
fwrite($resFile, $outdata );
fclose($resFile);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you changed the file permissions in your server.

Comment: Originally I thought that too, but it is happening now on a second server that is unrelated to the first time I saw this.  On my test server I changed the permissions to 777 and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Experiancing the same problem on a ubuntu 14-04 machine. round about 2 weeks the sftp connection with a library trying to connect with file_put_contents("ssh2.sftp://{Resource id #220}/....", $content) does not work any more and the are no errors, the browser response with "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

i cant figure out whats the problem... 
in this very moment of file_put_contents the system breaks...

Comment: ok, very easy to proof whats wrong. in the terminal on the machine open the interactive php "php -a", try:

php > fopen("ssh2.sftp://test", "r");

and u ll get a segmentation fault!